# SQL - How to get a different date output?

Tags: sql, oracle

The table lists dates like this:

```
21-OCT-09
```

I'm trying to write a query that lists the dates like this :

```
10/21/2009
```

So far I've tried

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE....) FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: You can change the date format using nls parameter in the dbms

Comment: Do you want another default for date display or do you want to display the date differently in just certain queries with `TO_CHAR`?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner I want to display the date differently in just certain queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TO_CHAR`. Here are the allowed formats: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#CDEHIFJA.

You want `'mm/dd/yyyy'`:

```
select to_char(mydate, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
from mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should hopefully work. I'll put it in a single-liner

In Oracle

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY')  from DUAL;
```

In SQL Server

```
SELECT replace(convert(NVARCHAR, getdate(), 101), ' ', '/');
```

Comment: That looks so clumsy, it can't be Oracle. I guess it's SQL Server?

Comment: hmm yeah. It's sql server. Didn't notice the Oracle tag !